# Deleting audio files for android in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, file, audio

I ma working on a music player and i added the delete song feature but its not working as expected. What i assumed as i implemented my current method to delete the song is just deleting the file the usual way

**Here is how i do it**

```
 File songToDelete = File(song.filePath);

...some irrelevant code...

if(result){
  var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.storage.request().then((value) {
        if(value.isGranted){
            songToDelete.delete().catchError((err){
              print(err);
              showToast('Sorry, an error occurred');
            }).then((value){
              showToast('Song deleted!');
            });
        }
      });
    }else{
  await songToDelete.delete().catchError((err){
    print(err);
  }).then((value){
    print(value);
  });
  }
}
```

Initially i thought the song was deleted but the app just did not update the songs list but on opening and restarting another music player on my device, I saw the song there. When i try to play it though, it just skips to the next song so I figured the song file was actually deleted. Since i don't know much about android storage and how the file system is managed, i'm stuck at this. Id appreciate help.

Comment: Which storage permissions have you registered in your Android manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Those are all the permissions i registered